# C++ equivalent to b[1:] in python

Tags: python, c++, slice

How can I write python `b[1:]` in C++, which is an integer array index
from 1 to n. Is it possible to represent it using vector?

```
def select_sort_rec(a):
     if len(a) <= 1:
        return a
     else:
        b = list(a)
        min_index = b.index(min(b))
        aux = b[min_index]
        b[min_index] = b[0]
        b[0] = aux
        return [aux] + select_sort_rec(b[1:])
```

Comment: There is no direct way to slice an array like you can do in python, but there are several other ways to accomplish it. It depends on what type you use to represent the array. Show us the C++ code where you want to do this and we can help you.

Comment: It would help me a lot if you just show one using Vector STL perhaps.

Comment: If you remember that such "arrays" in Python are really called *lists*, then you could easily find support for that in [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: There you go, the duplicate even does exactly the same slicing!

Comment: @MaxLanghof what would be the equivalent of python b[1: n-1] using C++ vector?

Comment: @TechMe Try to understand what is happening in the linked answer. Then you should be able to answer that question yourself. But you can also find the answer by searching for it.